# How do I use `JSON.parse`'s reviver function to add data to each object in an array?

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have the following JSON object saved in a variable like this:

```
var musicList = {
  "files": [
        {
          "title": "Ironic"
        },
        {
          "title": "It's Beginning To Look A Lot Like Christmas"
        },
        {
          "title": "Sweet Dreams"
        }
      ] 
};
```

This is for a learning exercise which has us turn this JSON object to a string and then parse it back again into an object...

```
console.log(musicList); // prints the object in the musicList variable
var stringifiedMusic = JSON.stringify(musicList);
console.log(stringifiedMusic); // prints the string version of the musicList object
```

But I am not expecting the results I want, which is to add a simple incrementing ID number to each object in the array with the key of `files`.  I believe I am not writing the reviver function properly...

```
var parsedMusic = JSON.parse(stringifiedMusic, function(key, value) {
  var idIncrementor = 0;
  var incrementorObject = [
    {id: idIncrementor}
  ];

  if (key === 'files') {
    idIncrementor++;
    return value.map(function (item, index) {
      return Object.assign({}, item, incrementorObject[index]);
    });
  }
  return value;
});
```

As it is now, this only seems to add the `id: 0` key value pair to the first object but not the others.  This must be because the `if (key === 'files')...` statement is only ever true just once.  What would I check for in my `if` statement that would be true for the three objects in the array if I only have `key` and `value` arguments passing into the function?

Comment: What's the point to this? Why are you converting your object to JSON just to convert it right back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a new object. The `map` function, if used correctly, will return a new array(with new objects). And you can use the index provided by `map` to get your id.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wusicegela/edit?js,console)

```
var musicList = {
  "files": [
        {
          "title": "Ironic"
        },
        {
          "title": "It's Beginning To Look A Lot Like Christmas"
        },
        {
          "title": "Sweet Dreams"
        }
      ] 
};

var stringifiedMusic = JSON.stringify(musicList);

var parsedMusic = JSON.parse(stringifiedMusic, function(key, value) {

  if (key === 'files') {
    return value.map(function (item, index) {
      item.id = index;
      return item;
    });
  }
  return value;
});

console.log("parsedMusic", parsedMusic)
```

Comment: Your .map isn't creating new objects. And I still don't see the point of creating JSON just to parse it right afterward.

Comment: [JLRishe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1945651/jlrishe), he says right away that this "is for a learning exercise". The point is that he learns how to use the methods.
[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.` 
It's a new array with new stuff in it. If you don't believe me, compare `musicList` + `parsedMusic` with console logs.

Comment: If `map` had no return, then it'd be manipulating the original array/objects.
Also from the docs: `map does not mutate the array on which it is called` (although callback, if invoked, may do so).

Comment: Oh wow, you're doubling down on the "map() creates new objects" thing. No, you're wrong. `map()` creates a new array. It does not necessarily create new objects. The callback you pass to `map` _can_ create new objects, but in your case, it's not. It's mutating existing objects. You can observe that right here: https://jsfiddle.net/h2y65m7f/

Comment: I stand corrected. However, my example is not mutating the original objects in `musicList`, it's mutating the parsed/stringified objects.